# Pesach: Kitniyos Plants

Tags: minhag, passover, agriculture, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, vegetables

Vegans have a hard time getting enough protein on *Pesach*.

Is the plant that grows from a *kitniyos* seed also *kitniyos* on *Pesach*?

What if the seed is still attached?

Comment: You mean like corn leaves? How would that be different from wheat leaves which are completely permitted to eat on Pesach?

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, I did not know that. Maybe you can answer that with a kal vachomer and a source?

Comment: Not really relevant, but are _kitniyos_ plants' leaves and stalks higher in protein than other leaves and stalks? I wouldn't have thought so.

Comment: @msh210 [Maybe not.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=protein+content+100+g+bean+sprouts+vs+100+g+vegetables)

Comment: I'm not sure why this question got down-votes. Some applications would be bean/alfalfa sprouts,  mustard greens, fennel leaves/bulbs & anise leaves. I heard that some rabbis consider pumpkin seeds kitniyot, though I assume the pumpkin itself would be okay. Further afield would be the question (is it a question?) of buckwheat honey.

Comment: Upon further investigation I found asparagus and spinach to have about 40% protein in their dry mass.

Comment: [Arukh HaShulchan OC 465:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A1%D7%94#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A1.D7.94_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90) permits giving wheat stalks to animals to eat on Pesach.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly CYLOR for any practical halacha if someone is protein-deficient (though missing *eight days* likely won't be a make or break someone who has a relatively healthy diet for the vast majority of the rest of the year), [this](https://images.shulcloud.com/193/uploads/Other/Pesach-Guide-5773.pdf) Pesach guide interestingly writes that dill and fennel seeds are considered kitniyos, but their leaves are not. That would seem to imply the author holds kitniyos leaves are not an issue. Although there are other things in his Pesach guide which I'm not sure the OU or STAR-K would agree with, [Rabbi Larry Rothwachs](https://larryrothwachs.com/bio/) certainly seems to be a *talmid chacham* based on his distinguished Rabbinic roles.